# Keyboard Not Hiding on Form Input Blur

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, virtual-keyboard

I am using a [jQuery keyboard plug-in](http://project.cahnory.fr/jquery.keyboard/) that loads when you focus on an input/textarea field, and hides when that focus is removed. Works as advertised on a basic html form page.

The problem arises when I use this keyboard on a modal window on the same page. The keyboard will load when I focus on any of the modal input fields but it will not hide when focus is removed. It stays out until I reload the page.

I am isolating the issue at line 89 in jquery.keyboard.form.js where the binding on blur events isn't working with the modal (though it does for focus). At least, this is my guess on where it's failing.

```
$('[type="text"],textarea').bind('blur.keyboard', function(e) {
    unsetFocus($(e.target));
});
```

This script is used to keep the keyboard active on modal layover.

```
//Keep the keyboard above modal
$(function(){
    $('body').keyboard({keyboard: 'qwerty', plugin: 'form'});
    $('.keyboard').css('z-index', '20000');
});
```

You can test this for yourself on http://testing.expologic.com/test-keyboard/index.html

Comment: Obviously it works without clicking the modal link, have you used the same code as the first page?

Comment: I wrote that it works without the modal. It's _with_ the modal that I specified wasn't working correctly.

Comment: Well done.  Read what I typed.  Actually, enjoy fixing it.

Comment: My mistake; I do have two pages in this example. Loading the keyboard a second time into the modal would not produce the desired result. It would only, theoretically, load said keyboard within the modal. I need it to remain on the parent page.